# Custom functions and workflows with publicly distributed slack boltjs app

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

### Background

I have a slack app that is publicly distributed and i've used boltJs with express to build this app. I have created a slash command that will let me input 3 paramters from 3 different dropdowns which will then generate a report/graph and send the graph as an image to the user in slack.

I want the user to schedule the report so that it gets delivered to him/her on the selected day/time with the same parameters. I am looking into slack workflow builder for the same since it enables the user to schedule messages.

### The Problem

The boltJs documentation shows how to build custom functions, triggers and workflows for an app with Socket mode turned on (app that is not publicly distributed). It uses `slack cli` to publish/distribute the custom function to a particular workspace. How do I implement the same for a publicly distributed app? Or, is there a better way to do this?